# Conditional Statements Array Looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create an image slider for a website, I want to learn why my array won't go back to zero after finishing the first iteration and keep on iterating. I want the slider to iterate on and on automatically.

```js
function run() {
  for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    (function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (i == imgArray.length) {
          i = 0;
        }

        imgContainer.style.background = imgArray[i];
      }, 3000 * e);
    })(i);
  };
  imgContainer.style.height = '100vh';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition `i == imgArray.length` inside the loop is never true, since the loop runs until `i < imgArray.length`. You could use `<=` instead as Ali Abug Hijleh suggested, but I think it would be easier to maintain if you explicitly show the loop should run forever with `while (true)` and use the `%` operator to get the right index:

```js
function run() {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    (function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        imgContainer.style.background = imgArray[i % imgArray.length];
      }, 3000 * e);
    })(i);
  };
  imgContainer.style.height = '100vh';
  ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` will never reach the `imgArray.length` because the loop only works when `i` is **less than** `imgArray.length` (since you use `i < imgArray.length` as the condition)

Try `if (i == imgArray.length -1) { ... }` instead.

Comment: I already modified this as you suggest. Now it goes all the way to the end of the img array and after that it goes to the first img. How can I get the for loop to get going after arriving to the first value again?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your for loop ends before you reset it to zero because you reset it to zero inside a setTimeout